# How can I get unformatted ip address information in the shell?

Tags: command-line, networking, ifconfig

I'm writing a shell script which needs information on the state of the network connection - the basic stuff like ip address, subnet, netmask and so on.

I could just use `ifconfig` and sed/grep for the information, but I was hoping there was a cleaner way to do this - possibly using the `ip` command, or similar utilities.

I'm looking for something which could give the following results:

```
$ (magic command) ip
192.168.1.1
$ (magic command) netmask
255.255.255.0
$ (magic command) subnet
192.168.0.0
```

and possibly similar things for network gateway/dns servers.

Does such a command exist? Perhaps there's an `--unformatted` flag for `ip` or `ifconfig`? Am I too hopeful/naive?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also use `ifdata` to get information without parsing output of `ip` with `grep`, `awk` or other tools:

```
[~]$ ifdata -pa eth0
192.168.246.161
[~]$ ifdata -pn eth0
255.255.240.0
[~]$ ifdata
Usage: ifdata [options] iface
     -e   Reports interface existence via return code
     -p   Print out the whole config of iface
    -pe   Print out yes or no according to existence
    -pa   Print out the address
    -pn   Print netmask
    -pN   Print network address
    -pb   Print broadcast
    -pm   Print mtu
    -ph   Print out the hardware address
    -pf   Print flags
    -si   Print all statistics on input
   -sip   Print # of in packets
   -sib   Print # of in bytes
   -sie   Print # of in errors
   -sid   Print # of in drops
   -sif   Print # of in fifo overruns
   -sic   Print # of in compress
   -sim   Print # of in multicast
    -so   Print all statistics on output
   -sop   Print # of out packets
   -sob   Print # of out bytes
   -soe   Print # of out errors
   -sod   Print # of out drops
   -sof   Print # of out fifo overruns
   -sox   Print # of out collisions
   -soc   Print # of out carrier loss
   -som   Print # of out multicast
  -bips   Print # of incoming bytes per second
  -bops   Print # of outgoing bytes per second
```

Comment: Take in account that you will need to install `moreutils` package.

Answer (score 4):

The `ip` command supercedes the `ifconfig` command and supports the `-o` option for easier automatic parsing.

For example:

```
ip -o addr show dev wlan0|awk '$3=="inet"{print $4}'
```

will produce something like:

```
192.168.0.2/24
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can try to grep and awk the information from the output like this: `ip addr show eth0 | grep 'inet ' | awk '{ print $2}'`

Your output should look like this: `192.168.1.201/24`

`ip addr show eth0` gets you the information from eth0. `grep 'inet '` is for IPv4. 'inet6' should be used for IPv6. `awk '{ print $2}'` simply reduces the output further to the second series of characters.

The netmask can be determined from the /24 after the IP address.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is a way to make your own commands and get your information..

- To get your **IpAddress** save following command in any file say `myipaddr`:

  ```
  ifconfig | grep 'inet addr:' | grep -v '127.0.0.1' | awk '{print $2}' | cut -f2 -d:
  ```
- Similarly to get **NetMask** save following command in file say  `mymask`:

  ```
  ifconfig | grep 'inet addr:' | grep -v '127.0.0.1' | awk '{print $4}' | cut -f2 -d:
  ```
- To get **Bcast** (subnet) save following command in another file say `mysubnet`:

  ```
  ifconfig | grep 'inet addr:' | grep -v '127.0.0.1' | awk '{print $3}' | cut -f2 -d:
  ```
- Then make all file executable and copy or move it to `/bin` directory:

  ```
  $ sudo chmod +x myipaddr mysubnet mymask
  $ sudo cp myipaddr mysubnet mymask /usr/bin
  ```

Now to get your desired information you need to just open a **Terminal** and run any of this command. For example:

```
    $ sudo myipaddr
```

Should display something like this:

`192.168.1.11`

```
    $ sudo mymask
```

should display something like:

`255.255.255.0`

```
    $ sudo mysubnet
```

should display something like:

`192.168.1.255`

Comment: isn't better 766 for the scripts permissions? also, making root owner of them isn't bad idea either.

Comment: Yes it is not a bad idea, but this command is meant for personal use, so it is better to use command name with just its name, instead of using `sudo` everytime.